# TypeError: THREE.DeviceOrientationControls is not a function

Tags: three.js, typeerror

So I keep getting this error when calling

```
    controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I have DeviceOrientationControls.js the same location as everything else.
Thanks

Comment: add open/close parens `()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of **THREE.js** are you using? This class appeared in library from **r72**. Also you need to load it additionally from main build as it is located not in the main three.js build file but in `examples/js/controls` directory.